# updating array using javascript and angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects containing following properties

```
vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network=[
{
    columnNo: ""
    componentId: "EC1"
    componentName: "CircuitBreaker"
    deviceName: "com.se.ed.exchange_format.electrical_taxonomy.ElectricalDeviceCircuitBreaker"
    deviceProperties: Object
    inTerminal: "ECT1"
    outTerminal: "ECT2"
    productId: ""
    properties: Object
    symbolId: ""
    __proto__: 
},
{
    columnNo: ""
    componentId: "EC1"
    componentName: "CircuitBreaker"
    deviceName: "com.se.ed.exchange_format.electrical_taxonomy.ElectricalDeviceCircuitBreaker"
    deviceProperties: Object
    inTerminal: "ECT1"
    outTerminal: "ECT2"
    productId: ""
    properties: Object
    symbolId: ""
    __proto__: 
}
]
```

Now based on some condition I am trying to add `functionalName` property inside these objects , but when I add or update one object , automatically another object is getting update with same property and value

```
angular.forEach(vm.selectedSwitchBoardDetails.ElectricalFunction, function(item2, index2) {
    if(item2.label==item1.id.slice(-1))
    {
        for(var i=0; i<net; i++)
        {
            if(vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].functionalName!==undefined)
            {
                delete vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].functionalName;
                vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].functionalName=item2.value;
                 vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].columnNo=item1.id.slice(-1);
            }
            else{
                vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].functionalName=item2.value;
                vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].columnNo=item1.id.slice(-1);
            }

        }

    }
});
```

where `item1=vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i]`

and `net` is length of the above array .

What is the problem in my code ?? Is it related to javascript Object copy and reference related problem ?? any help is appreciable.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `item2.value` is a reference type property, then all `functionalName` properties will point to the same object (since it's a reference type). Same thing applies to the `item1.id` property.

If that's the case, you should use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].functionalName=angular.copy(item2.value);
            vm.projectJson.project.switchboards[index].switchboard[index1].NF.network[i].columnNo=angular.copy(item1.id.slice(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your objects are refering to original object, that is from memory so prefer to use

```
angular.copy(src, destn);
```

that will resolve your problem

Comment: Could you please add plunkr or jsfiddle demo